# Tips for email log script for postfix

Tags: shell, grep

I wrote a simple script that shows sent email from mail.log. It uses `grc` to color the results.

```
log='/var/log/mail.log'
grc grep "status=sent" $log | \
egrep -ve 'postfix/(cleanup|pickup|master|qmgr|smtpd|local|pipe)'
```

It works quite well but I would like to filter out some of the noice.
How can I filter out stuff like this...

```
delay=0.34, delays=0.01/0.02/0.14/0.16, dsn=2.0.0,
```

Comment: Can you show us a few lines of the `mail.log` to get a better view of the log file

Comment: Apr 24 14:59:30 smtp postfix/smtp[30031]: 1EA2D817C3: to=<admin@example.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=mail.example.com[1.2.3.4]:25, delay=0.31, delays=0.01/0.02/0.25/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 68A251000A2)

Answer (score 0):

This works well for Sent email on Postfix/Debian:

```
# Script to list sent emails on Postfix/Debian
log='/var/log/mail.log'
grep "status=sent" $log | \
egrep -ve 'postfix/(cleanup|pickup|master|qmgr|smtpd|local|pipe)' | cut -f2 -d"="  | cut -f1 -d">" | cut -c2-
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for Incoming email on Postfix/Debian:

```
# Script to list recived emails
log='/var/log/mail.log'
grep "from=" $log | \
egrep -ve 'postfix/(submission|cleanup|pickup|master|smtps|smtpd|local|pipe)' | cut -f2 -d"="  | cut -f1 -d">" | cut -c2-
```